# Sharing files stored inside Firebase realtimeDB outside react web app

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Hi everyone I have a react + Java web application. In this web app i have users files, pdf mostly, stored inside Firebase realtimeDB. Is it possible to share a user file outside of the web app , to a non-registered user, in read-only mode? Maybe via link or something?
If not, how do I achieve such thing as sharing files outside my web app?

Comment: You can get a download link from firebase. I recommend you to read the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

Comment: @MithatErcan thanks for the suggestion